# Domain changes when copying

Tags: dns, subdomain

I have set up a webserver and connected a dns with the domain shown bellow to it. The Problem is that when I copy and paste the domain it changes to a weird string, as shown bellow.

The original domain i used is "https://negertöter.de" and it changes to "https://xn--negertter-57a.de/".

Is this because of the "ö" or what's the problem, can i fix this or do i have to register a new domain without the "ö" to get rid of the problem?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you see is ok and works as designed. What you see is not a "weird" string, it is the ASCII representation of Internationalized Domain Names aka IDNs which are domain names using characters outside of the ASCII range.

You can search for IDNA specification to understand more about that.

Browsers support it differently depending on the TLD and the characters in the domain name. For security reasons, they may not display the IDN in "Unicode" form and fall back to ACE (ASCII Compatible Encoding) form as you witnessed.

You don't have to register anything else, `xn--negertter-57a.de` is the correct ASCII representation per IDNA specification of IDN `negertöter.de`.

Your registrar, DNS provider, and/or website provider should be able to explain things further and guide you as needed.